# Going to print multiple cards in fixed size

Tags: printing, printer, google-docs, iwork-pages, fixed-width

I need to print out about 80 "cards" for an invitation and to fit the envelope I need to print them in a very exact size. Each "card" has to be 5cm in width and 7.5cm in height.

Instead of just printing one card one one A4 paper (I only have access to a regular A4 laser printer, nothing fancy) I would like to arrange them into e.g. 4 cards per paper, thus saving some paper.

I'm on a Apple computer with no MS Office, just the Apple Pages, Numbers, etc.
I've access to Google Drive and thus Google Docs.

I've tried to get it to work in both Pages, Numbers, Docs, and Spreadsheet but no luck. 
It either can't get the correct dimensions or it gets really messed up on the page.

Is there a online service or an app for Mac OS which easy can set up such multiple "text boxes" and print them on a A4 sheet?

If I've explained myself unclear please let me know so I can elaborate.

Cheers,
- M